How to pass data to ModalBottomSheet from AppState?
I am following the NowInAndroid app model to create my own app.
In the top bar I have a button and I want that when clicking on it a ModalBottomSheet opens to play a text related to the content that is on the screen at that time.
My problem is that I don't know how to get that text or what is the best place to do it, applying a clean architecture.
I apologize for my long-windedness, but I want to explain the context as clearly as possible.
Initially, I show how theuiState is obtained in the ViewModel, by calling a UseCase:
@HiltViewModel
class UniversalisViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    val userDataRepository: UserDataRepository,
    getTopicWithDate: GetUniversalisUseCase,
    ) : ViewModel() {

    //...

    val uiState: StateFlow<UniversalisUiState> = combine(
        selectedTopicId,
        getTopicWithDate(
            sortBy = HomeSortField.ID,
            date = Utils.hoy.toInt(),
            topicId = selectedTopicId.value!!.toInt()
        ),
        UniversalisUiState::UniversalisData,
    ).stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
        initialValue = UniversalisUiState.Loading,
    )

    //...
}

sealed interface UniversalisUiState {
    data object Loading : UniversalisUiState
    data object Error : UniversalisUiState
    
    data class UniversalisData(
        val selectedTopicId: String?,
        val topics: List<UniversalisRequest>,
    ) : UniversalisUiState

    data object Empty : UniversalisUiState
}

I pass the ViewModel as a parameter to the route, to then work with the UiState:
fun UniversalisRoute(
    showBackButton: Boolean,
    onBackClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: UniversalisViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {
    val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    UniversalisScreen(
        uiState = uiState,
        modifier = modifier,
        onReaderClick = viewModel::onReaderClick,
        onBackClick = onBackClick,
    )

    //
}

UniversalisScreen is the screen in charge of displaying the content visible to the user. It should be noted that this content, although it is the same as that which must be read by voice in the TTS, has a different format on the screen, for example, applying styles, text sizes, etc. That is, the same content is treated in two different ways, one to display on the screen, with format, and another to be read by voice, without format and applying in this case some character substitutions to adapt it to voice reading.
This is the part of UniversalisScreen that displays the data on the screen:
if (uiState.topics.isNotEmpty()) {
    universalisBody(
        name = Utils.capitalize(LiturgyHelper.liturgyByType(uiState.selectedTopicId!!.toInt())),
        description = uiState.topics[0].data[0].fecha,
        universalis = uiState,
    )
}

In universalisBody I have the following:
private fun LazyListScope.universalisBody(
    name: String,
    description: String,
    universalis: UniversalisUiState.UniversalisData,

    ) {
    item {
        UniversalisHeader(name, description)
    }
    universalisResourceCards(universalis)
}

And in universalisResourceCards:
private fun LazyListScope.universalisResourceCards(
    universalis: UniversalisUiState,
) {
    when (universalis) {
        is UniversalisUiState.UniversalisData -> {
            universalisResourceCardItems(
                items = universalis.topics,
                topicId = universalis.selectedTopicId,
                itemModifier = Modifier.padding(24.dp),
            )
        }
        // ...
    }
}

From universalisResourceCardItems I call one function UniversalisResourceCardExpanded in which a differentiation must be made of the data that were obtained in the repository.
@Composable
fun UniversalisResourceCardExpanded(
    universalisResource: List<UniversalisRequest>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    topicId: String?,
) {
    Card(
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface),
    ) {
        Column {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
            ) {
                Column {
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(12.dp))
                    Row {
                        var title: String
                        topicId!!.toInt().let {
                            title = when {
                                it == 20 -> {
                                    val sancti = universalisResource[0].data[0].liturgia!!.liturgiaTypus as Alteri.Sancti
                                    sancti.sanctus.monthName
                                }

                                else -> {                                    
                                    universalisResource[0].data[0].liturgia!!.tempus!!.externus.toString()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        UniversalisResourceTitle(
                            title,
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth((.8f)),
                        )
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                    }
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(14.dp))
                    Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {                        
                        UniversalisResourceMetaData(universalisResource[0].data[0].liturgia!!.nomen)
                    }
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(14.dp))
                    var data = universalisResource[0].data[0]
                    Universalis(data, topicId = topicId, universalisResource[0].dynamic)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

As you can see, after differentiation to get the title, I call a composable called Universalis in which different screens will be called, depending on the class of the parameter data
Universalis(data, topicId = topicId, universalisResource[0].dynamic)

To get an idea of ​​what's in Universalis:
@Composable
fun Universalis(data: Universalis, topicId: String?, userData: UserDataDynamic) {
    val itemId = topicId!!.toInt()
    val onTap = { point: Offset -> }
    if (data.liturgia!!.liturgiaTypus is Sortable) {
        data.liturgia!!.liturgiaTypus?.sort()
    }

    /*
       This is a test, which works. 
       What I need is to call the screen that will read TTS 
       in a ModalBottomSheet, when the button that is loaded 
       from the start in AppState is pressed.
    */

    if (userData.useVoiceReader) {
        TextToSpeechScreen(data.getAllForRead())
    }


    /*
       These are the different screens that the user will see, 
       depending on the type of data parameter
    */
    
    when (itemId) {
        1 -> MixtusScreen(
            data = data.liturgia!!.liturgiaTypus as LHMixtus,
            calendarTime = data.timeFK,
            userData = userData,
            onTap = onTap
        )

        2 -> OfficiumScreen(
            data = data.liturgia!!.liturgiaTypus as LHOfficium,
            calendarTime = data.timeFK,
            userData = userData,
            onTap = onTap
        )
        //
    }
}

Sorry for the long explanation, the intention is to clarify the context as much as possible.
The attempt I have made to display the ModalBottomSheet when clicking on the button has been to pass an action with a onReaderClick  event to the top bar.
NiaTopAppBar(
    // ...
    readerIcon = NiaIcons.Reader,
    onReaderClick = { 
        showBottomSheet = true
        appState.textToRead //I can see "Lorem ipsum" here
    },
)

As a test, I have passed the repository as a parameter to the NiaAppState class, and I have created the variable textToRead
@Stable
class NiaAppState(
    val navController: NavHostController,
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    val windowSizeClass: WindowSizeClass,
    networkMonitor: NetworkMonitor,
    universalisRepository: UniversalisRepository,
    timeZoneMonitor: TimeZoneMonitor,
) {
    //...
    val shouldRead = universalisRepository.getReader()
}

My test works, if I put in the repository a method like this:
override fun getReader():String{
    return "Lorem ipsum"
}

But what I need is to get the data ready for voice reading, from the instance already created in the Universalis composable, by calling the getAllForRead() method of that instance.
My problem is that I don't know how to do this, applying a clean architecture in the style of Compose.
